# How to do label search and ordered with date or time in blogger?

Tags: javascript, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

I have a blog [Android Lad](http://androidlad.blogspot.com/) in this blog i started a tutorial for android beginners. When user click on Android Beginner it should show me only labelled with iamandroidbeginner and also sorted with date, means in reverse order. 
Can anybody help me to write javascript code for this particuler scenario???

Answer (score 0):

Change the post date you want to show at the first to the most recent and click update or try this JavaScript [code](http://yabtb.blogspot.com/2011/09/blogger-posts-chronological-order.html).

Comment: I missed script written in mentioned blog.... I use that script but unfortunately it always give an error " warn: no posts found?"  http://androidlad.blogspot.com/#order=ASC